# Option for Cascade Delete for References or On Delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, database-migration

In Rails 4.2, when creating a table or adding a reference via references or add_reference how do you specify that the foreign key should cascade on delete.

Command to generate scaffold:

```
rails g scaffold Child parent:references name:string
```

Resulting migration:

```
create_table :childs do |t|
  t.references :parent, index: true, foreign_key: true
  t.string :name

  t.timestamps null: false
end
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

This should work

```
create_table :childs do |t|
  t.references :parent, index: true, foreign_key: {on_delete: :cascade}
  t.string :name

  t.timestamps null: false
end
```

According to `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::TableDefinition#references`, if a hash is specified on the `foreign_key` option, it is directly passed down into the `foreign_key` method.

source:

```
foreign_key(col.to_s.pluralize, foreign_key_options.is_a?(Hash) ? foreign_key_options : {}) if foreign_key_options
```

Answer (score 10):

Also note that if you already have the table setup, you can generate a migration to update the foreign_key by doing the following:

```
  def up
    remove_foreign_key :children, :parent
    add_foreign_key :children, :parent, on_delete: :cascade
  end

  def down
    remove_foreign_key :children, :parent
    add_foreign_key :children, :parent
  end
```