# How do I create a foreign key with a cascading delete constraint in my Rails 5 migration?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, migration, ruby-on-rails-5, cascading-deletes

I'm using Rails 5 with PostGres 9.5 . I want to create a foreign key to my addresses table from my search_codes table so I created this migration

```
class CreateSearchCodeTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :search_codes do |t|
      t.string :code
      t.references :address, type: :string, index: true, foreign_key: true, on_delete: :cascade
      t.index ["code"], name: "index_search_codes_on_code", unique: true, using: :btree
    end
  end
end
```

However what gets created is the following.  Notice the cascading portion of the constraint didn't seem to get created

```
myapp=> \d search_codes;
                                Table "public.search_codes"
   Column   |       Type        |                         Modifiers
------------+-------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------
 id         | integer           | not null default nextval('search_codes_id_seq'::regclass)
 code       | character varying |
 address_id | character varying |
Indexes:
    "search_codes_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "index_search_codes_on_code" UNIQUE, btree (code)
    "index_search_codes_on_address_id" btree (address_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_rails_6bd9792e3b" FOREIGN KEY (address_id) REFERENCES addresses(id)
```

How do I create a migration with a cascading foreign key constraint using the Rails 5 migration and PostGres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like that [ReferenceDefinition](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/20e726d231c16888efa78972187b4cf8cd54002e/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb#L76) doesn't accept `on_delete` option. You can specify on delete with [add_foreign_key](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_foreign_key):

```
class CreateSearchCodeTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :search_codes do |t|
      t.string :code
      t.references :address, type: :string, index: true
      t.index ["code"], name: "index_search_codes_on_code", unique: true, using: :btree
    end

    add_foreign_key :search_codes, :addresses, on_delete: :cascade
  end
end
```

Comment: Cool.  I hate it when things that should work (like specifyihng "on_delete") don't.

Answer (score 1):

From this link for a previous version of Rails,
[Option for Cascade Delete for References or On Delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30154798/option-for-cascade-delete-for-references-or-on-delete)

This 
t.references :parent, index: true, **foreign_key: {on_delete: :cascade}**

Seems to work

Edit: note that it also appears you don't need 'index: true'.  It creates an index as well.